# Any documentation available for r2 other than official book

Tags: debugging, crackme, radare2

I am interested in learning and using radare2 as a toolset for reverse engineering. But I want ANY other resource for learning this tools other than **radare2 book**, preferably a video series. What I am interested in is solving crackmes and executables debugging.

Comment: could you please explain why the negative voting

Comment: please check on youtube

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote [some articles](https://dustri.org/b/archives.html) (search for *radare2*) about using r2 for crackmes, and there is a [talk](http://www.rada.re/r/talks.html) section on the official website.

Also you can find useful articles from the [blog](http://radare.today).

Also, feel free to come ask questions on the irc channel.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/maijin/workshop2015

And of course just join the chat room on freenode #radare2 and ask questions.

Comment: this is great but this looks like a slides for some videos where can I find these videos thanks

Comment: From his besides keynote. But it's good enough.

Comment: No videos yet for my slides sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

We collect useful links about using radare2 on our [forum](https://forum.reverse4you.org/showthread.php?t=2107)  (jvoisin blog too :) )

Comment: In fact, even if you link may be valuable, the policy of Stack-exchange is to prefer lengthy (and, as much as possible, self-contained) explanation. Pointing to external website is not really a good idea, especially if you do only that.

Comment: Sry, corrected. Author ask resources about using and I pointed place where we collect request things (I have got a same question/problem early).

Comment: No problem! I don't blame you in particular. I just remember the rule for everybody! :-) (you seems to be upvoted anyway, so your answer must be somehow relevant for some users).